# After extract the data from xml, data has to store in SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, xml, nodelist

i have written the Java program that extract the data from xml and provides below output.
Once the extraction done, data has to store in SQL Database. Please help me to add the data in SQL database,

this below output has to store in Database,

**Output:-**

```
Root element of the doc is geodata
Total no of people : 2
Address : 2344 States Drive, MA 01213, USA
Phone Number : 333-222-2222
Salary : $3000
Pension : $3000
Address : 2345 Gates Drive, PA 11213, USA
Phone Number : 444-222-2222
Salary : $3500
Pension : $3500
```

**Source Code:-**

```
package com.techassignment;

import java.io.File;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 

public class readxml 
{


        public static void main (String argv [])
        {
        try {

                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\mkar\\workspace\\techassignment - new\\src\\com\\techassignment\\testFinal.xml"));

                // normalize text representation
                doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
                System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
                     doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


                NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
                int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
                System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);

                for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++){


                    Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                    if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


                        Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;

                        //-------
                        NodeList addressList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("address");
                        Element addressElement = (Element)addressList.item(0);

                        NodeList textFNList = addressElement.getChildNodes();
                        System.out.println("Address : " + 
                               ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                        //-------
                        NodeList phonenumberList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("phonenumber");
                        Element phonenumberElement = (Element)phonenumberList.item(0);

                        NodeList textLNList = phonenumberElement.getChildNodes();
                        System.out.println("Phone Number : " + 
                               ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                        //----
                        NodeList salaryList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("salary");
                        Element salaryElement = (Element)salaryList.item(0);

                        NodeList textAgeList = salaryElement.getChildNodes();
                        System.out.println("Salary : " + 
                               ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                        //----
                        NodeList PensionList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("pension");
                        Element PensionElement = (Element)salaryList.item(0);

                        NodeList textPensionList = salaryElement.getChildNodes();
                        System.out.println("Pension : " + 
                               ((Node)textPensionList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        //------


                    }//end of if clause


                }//end of for loop with s var


            }catch (SAXParseException err) {
            System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line " 
                 + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
            System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());

            }catch (SAXException e) {
            Exception x = e.getException ();
            ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

            }catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace ();
            }
            //System.exit (0);

        }//end of main


}
```

Comment: it's just data... connect to your db, whip up an INSERT query, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method say insert(root,noOfPeople,Address,phNo,salary) and pass all the data you wanted to insert into the data base in the parameters values one by one so that it inserts row wise

Row 1 in the data base will be -

```
   Address : 2344 States Drive, MA 01213, USA
   Phone Number : 333-222-2222
   Salary : $3000
   Pension : $3000
```

Row 2 in the data will be -

```
Address : 2345 Gates Drive, PA 11213, USA
Phone Number : 444-222-2222
Salary : $3500
Pension : $3500
```

also if you don't have any idea how to store data then read for JDBC in java.
also you can try 
1. [How to store data in Java? Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751273/how-to-store-data-in-java-database)
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm
3.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm

Comment: I thought of do the same. Create a method and pass the values and store it in a table.

**Since i am new to this topic. So can you give me that method to do same?**

Comment: Do you know how to insert into database i.e about JDBC connections?

Comment: I am sorry i don't know.

Comment: i can provide that method to you but that will only be copying for you not learning.and programming is about learning not copying at least you are beginner if you really want then learn first.i have mentioned a link go through it ,it will help you to get and understand how to make connections with the database and use queries as making ineraction with the DB is important thats going to help in future also.Do learn it.

Comment: all the best.Keep Programming (y)

Comment: It would be helpful if you give me that method. I'll learn that but i need to submit my tech assignment tomorrow. so can you?

Comment: try the new link mentioned i can provide i know what you are using what database what tables.its better you learn first it will not take time more then half hr.

Comment: yeah i checked and i did the below, but still it shows the error **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.**


`int i =st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO newppl(name,address,phnumber,salary,pension) values('"+nameList+"','"+addressList+"','"+phonenumberList+"','"+salaryList+"','"+PensionList+"')");`

Comment: Is this correct one? I have created the table in SQL Server and created all the columns in varchar(50); Database connection successfull.
Yes i am getting the below error,

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)**

Comment: try executing step by step and trace the error.or mail me you code.

Comment: I have fixed the issue and it is adding the values to my db.
Thank You :-) I amn't having yuor email id. could you share it?

Comment: there is no email id in your profile, i checked several times.
say hi to my mail id : karnee@outlook.com